# specify width just for chrome/ff/ie

Tags: css, width

Is there a way of spec a width in CSS individually for Chrome/Firefox/Internet Explorere so it only takes effect in one of those browsers?

Does anyone know some hacks?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Chances are that whatever you're trying to do is just broken... why would you want to set different widths explicitly for different browsers like that?

Comment: i wanna do that, because the widths of input and textareas are not the same in that browsers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use either server side or client side (e.g. javascript) code to determine the user agent, and act different accordingly.

Like Demian asked in a comment: what are you trying to do? And: what have you tried yet? Without further details it's hard to help out.

Also note people will typically be reluctant to answer this type of question, as in many cases the better solution is the one that works in all browsers.